# Why does View('index') work but not View::make('index') in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller,

I'm returning

`return View('index')` which returns the appropriate php file.

However, when i try `return View::make('index')` I get a

```
FatalErrorException in line 28:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found
```

What is wrong?

I'd like to eventually do `return View::make('index')->with('user',$user)` but that gives an unknown object error on the view side.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the actual view but the class View

You can either reference the alias in the root namespace by prepending a backslash:

```
return \View::make('index');
```

Or add an import statement at the top:

```
use View;
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work you just need to write use View; at the top of the class after namespace

Comment: Or use the root namespace in the call (`\View::make`)

Answer (score 0):

For pass variable in view page in laravel5 you can use

```
$data['user'] = 'test';
view('index.php',$data);
```

Then you can access the variable user in index.php page